# Does transparency have its own visual channel?

Tags: vision

Referring to (for example) [Visual Thinking for Design](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0123708966), the book discusses various low-level processing channels in the brain. Colour and orientation are two examples.

I wonder if transparency is another such channel; and if it isn't, how exactly transparency manifests itself within the brain.

Comment: 'low-level processing' is not a well defined term. Do you mean in V1 (primary visual cortex)? I think transparency is a higher-order feature that requires (object) boundary detection. I doubt you can see a big effect of it in the early visual processing where color and orientation are processed.

Comment: That is exactly my thinking, I doubt it is decoded in V1. You could also argue that transparency requires some higher level comparisons, as it involves both colour comparison, and some form of mental subtraction - you can attribute a single colour to two different objects. It kind of follow that you cannot attribute to it the term 'channel' - it's higher level.

Answer (score 4):

One interesting way to study transparency is by looking at cases where we perceive transparency even though there isn't any objective transparency.

Take this illusion from [Adelson (2000)](http://web.mit.edu/persci/people/adelson/pub_pdfs/gazzan.pdf) as an example.

[image]

In the both panels the diamonds have the same physical brightness (pixel value on the monitor), but our perception of the diamonds on the right is warped by the seemingly-transparent dark stripe that covers the diamonds on the top. Thus, even low-level image features like brightness are perceptually warped by the way our brain perceives the structure of the image.

There are a large number of papers on mathematical models of illusory transparency perception. A starting point might be [Anderson (1997)](http://web.mit.edu/persci/people/bart/Perception_Neon.pdf) and the references within. But, the general message from this research is that we sometimes perceive transparency as the result of imposing some kind of higher-order structure to make sense of the image.

Comment: That's a great answer, I only wish it would address the question more directly. The answer offers support to the idea that transparency is a higher-level operation, thus cannot have its own channel.